# Visual Studio C++ "Automatically format completed block on }"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-formatting

Visual Studio has this setting for C#, but I can't find it for C++. "Automatically format completed block on }" I used this feature a lot while working on C# stuff & now that I'm back on C++ (which I prefer), I miss the feature. How can I set this up? I assume I'd have to use a 3rd party plugin or something at this point, but I can't find any relevant ones in all my searching.

What the feature does: If I have a section of code & type '{' before it, then type '}' after it, it will automatically tab it in to match the tabbing rules that make the code easier to read.

Ex:

Start off with some code:

```
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    j += i;
}
```

---

Add a start bracket somewhere:

```
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    {
    j += i;
}
```

---

Add an end-bracket, and the contained code is automatically tabbed in for me:

```
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;
    {
        j += i;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Smart remark*: With `vim` that is trivial, on typing `}`, press the sequence `<ESC>V%=`... of course `vim` is not really Visual Studio :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's not really the same thing, is it?  That's 4 extra keys.  Or are you saying that sets vim up to do the formatting automatically from that point on?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Can be mapped to a key combination, so it would not be fully automated, but can be as simple as `<C-F>`... and it is possible that there is a way to get this to be performed automatically... mapping `}` in insert mode to write `}` and then press the key combination followed by an extra `a` to go back to insert mode... ( `:inoremap } }^[v%=%a` will do that... when in insert mode } is pressed it types the }, then exits to normal mode, selects the region, formats, moves back to the insertion point and enters insertion mode again )

Comment: @ATaylor: I rolled back your edit, because this question *does* have something to do with C++.  It has to do with a tool (a very popular tool) that is used to write C++ code, and it's specifically about that tool's use for that language (rather than being a language-neutral question about a code editor).  Besides that, most people filter on language tags, and by removing them entirely, you've doomed the question to not be seen by many people who might have an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, I see. In that case, I apologize. Apparently I have been mistaken and premature in my judgement. Thank you for alerting me.

Comment: It already works that way when you press enter after typing the {.  Tinker with the settings if you don't get that.  There's otherwise no parity between the code formatters for C++ and C#, they are very distinctive chunks of code with separate teams that work on it.

Comment: It works that way when writing new code, not when editing existing code. I want the end bracket to tab in existing code when I decide to surround it with brackets. So no, what I'm asking for does not currently happen. I'm in a big system of old code and fixing things. This comes up more than you'd think.

Comment: If it helps any, I've got Visual Assist X installed as well. I can potentially install other things too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in Visual Studio 2013. Make sure you have it enabled in Options under Text Editor->C/C++->Formatting->General. The option is "Automatically format block when I type a }".

Comment: Good to know.  I am currently using VS2010 and this could be a good reason to upgrade sometime soon.