# How to format automatically scope on last brace in VS C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, formatting

When I work in VS 2010 C# (not C++) when I put last brace for given scope, entire scope is nicely reformatted.

But when I work in C++ (previously VS 2010, now 2012) this does not happen, of course better or worse, I could select scope, trigger formatting, but I would like to do it, as it is done in C#.

So how to do it?

Comment: VS 2013 has formatting features.

Comment: @Simple, I am not buying person in the company :-).

Comment: In vim you would just do `=aB`. And the question was already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799866/visual-studio-c-automatically-format-completed-block-on). However, you may try [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f3f04cd-2866-4e47-a671-d1cc9cc3fb02) extension (I don't remember if it had this functionality though).